# If x < 0.5 in df 2, add "*" to value in df1

Tags: r

I have two data frames in R, one has my partial correlations and the other has the p-values for those correlations.

Example data:

```
x=c(.05,.05,.05,.05,.05)
y=c(.05,.05,.05,.05)
z=c(.05,.05,.05)

max_ln <- max(c(length(x), length(y), length(z)))
df1 <- data.frame(col1 = c(x,rep(NA, max_ln - length(x))),
                      col2 = c(y,rep(NA, max_ln - length(y))),
                      col3 = c(z,rep(NA, max_ln - length(z))))

x2=c(.06,.05,.001,.0001,.07)
y2=c(.07,.05,.08,.001)
z2=c(.06,.04,.02)

max_ln2 <- max(c(length(x2), length(y2), length(z2)))
df2 <- data.frame(col1 = c(x2,rep(NA, max_ln2 - length(x2))),
                  col2 = c(y2,rep(NA, max_ln2 - length(y2))),
                  col3 = c(z2,rep(NA, max_ln2 - length(z2))))
```

I want to add an * to each value in df1 if the value of the corresponding cell in df2 is < .05 (** for .01 and *** for .001).

I was thinking of using some combination of ifelse statements and paste0, but I am not sure at this point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `cut`:

```
df1[] <- paste0(as.matrix(df1), 
                replace(
                  cut(as.matrix(df2), 
                      c(0, 0.001, 0.01, 0.05, 1), 
                      labels = c(" ***", " **", " *", ""), 
                      right = FALSE),
                  which(is.na(as.matrix(df2))),
                  ""
                )
)

print(df1, right = FALSE)
#  col1     col2    col3  
#1 0.05     0.05    0.05  
#2 0.05     0.05    0.05 *
#3 0.05 **  0.05    0.05 *
#4 0.05 *** 0.05 ** NA    
#5 0.05     NA      NA
```

Usually, the stars are defined with `right = TRUE`, i.e., p <= 0.05 etc. In that case, you could use this:

```
df1[] <- paste0(as.matrix(df1), 
                symnum(as.matrix(df2), corr = FALSE, na = FALSE, 
                       cutpoints = c(0, 0.001, 0.01, 0.05, 1), 
                       symbols = c(" ***", " **", " *", ""))
)

print(df1, right = FALSE)
#  col1     col2     col3  
#1 0.05     0.05     0.05  
#2 0.05 *   0.05 *   0.05 *
#3 0.05 *** 0.05     0.05 *
#4 0.05 *** 0.05 *** NA    
#5 0.05     NA       NA
```

Comment: Thank you so much Roland, this worked perfectly!

Answer (score 2):

Using `findInterval` and this pipeline

```
> r <- unlist(df1)
> p <- unlist(df2)
> nna <- !is.na(p)
> r[nna] <- paste0(format(r[nna]), c("***", "** ", "*  ", "   ")[
+   findInterval(p[nna], c(0.001, 0.01, 0.05, Inf)) + 1])
> as.data.frame(array(r, dim(df2), dimnames(df2)))
     col1    col2    col3
1 0.05    0.05    0.05   
2 0.05    0.05    0.05*  
3 0.05**  0.05    0.05*  
4 0.05*** 0.05**     <NA>
5 0.05       <NA>    <NA>
```

---

*Data:*

```
> dput(df1)
structure(list(col1 = c(0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05), col2 = c(0.05, 
0.05, 0.05, 0.05, NA), col3 = c(0.05, 0.05, 0.05, NA, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))

> dput(df2)
structure(list(col1 = c(0.06, 0.05, 0.001, 1e-04, 0.07), col2 = c(0.07, 
0.05, 0.08, 0.001, NA), col3 = c(0.06, 0.04, 0.02, NA, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach, which admittedly relies on heavy dependencies, but may work for some folks' use cases.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

bind_rows(df1 %>% mutate(coltype = 'cor') %>% tibble::rowid_to_column(),
          df2 %>% mutate(coltype = 'pval') %>% tibble::rowid_to_column()) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = c(col1, col2, col3),
               names_to = 'col_num',
               values_to = 'col_value') %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = coltype, 
              values_from = col_value) %>% 
  mutate(new_cor = case_when(
    pval < 0.001 ~ paste0(cor, '***'),
    pval < 0.01 ~ paste0(cor, '**'),
    pval < 0.05 ~ paste0(cor, '*'),
    TRUE ~ as.character(cor))
  ) %>% 
  pivot_wider(id_cols = rowid, 
              names_from = col_num,
              values_from = new_cor) %>%
  select(-rowid)

# A tibble: 5 × 3
  col1    col2   col3 
  <chr>   <chr>  <chr>
1 0.05    0.05   0.05 
2 0.05    0.05   0.05*
3 0.05**  0.05   0.05*
4 0.05*** 0.05** NA   
5 0.05    NA     NA
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a function in the `gtools` package, [`stars.pval()`](https://search.r-project.org/CRAN/refmans/gtools/html/stars.pval.html):

> Generate significance stars (e.g. '***', '**', '*', '.') from p-values using R's standard definitions.

It uses `"."` for `0.05 < p <= 0.1`, so we can replace those with `""`.

```r
p_stars <- gtools::stars.pval(as.matrix(df2))
p_stars[p_stars == "."] <- ""
```

Then we simply `paste()` this and `as.matrix(df1)` together as in [Roland's nice answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77227161/12545041).

```r
df1[]  <- paste(as.matrix(df1), p_stars)
print(df1, right = FALSE)
#   col1     col2     col3  
# 1 0.05     0.05     0.05  
# 2 0.05 *   0.05 *   0.05 *
# 3 0.05 *** 0.05     0.05 *
# 4 0.05 *** 0.05 *** NA    
# 5 0.05     NA       NA
```